# Gcloud meanjs build failing via docker install

Tags: docker, gcloud, meanjs

I'm trying to deploy the following container on google cloud app engine using gcloud app deploy, it's the meanjs.org vanilla image. It uses a dockerfile, I'm new to docker and I'm trying to learn it on the fly, so if anyone can help that'd be great, thanks.
It looks as if the install of node via the dockerfile fails, I've checked node's documentation on github, and nothing has changed syntactically to what is in the existing dockerfile. I will attempt to recreate on my local workstation this morning, and will update this query shortly.
the errors are as follows..[first docker error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGl3s.png) [second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaVtx.png)[build fail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeGGD.png)
The docker file..

```html
# Build:
# docker build -t meanjs/mean .
#
# Run:
# docker run -it meanjs/mean
#
# Compose:
# docker-compose up -d

FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER MEAN.JS

# 80 = HTTP, 443 = HTTPS, 3000 = MEAN.JS server, 35729 = livereload, 8080 = node-inspector
EXPOSE 80 443 3000 35729 8080

# Set development environment as default
ENV NODE_ENV development

# Install Utilities
RUN apt-get update -q  \
 && apt-get install -yqq \
 curl \
 git \
 ssh \
 gcc \
 make \
 build-essential \
 libkrb5-dev \
 sudo \
 apt-utils \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install nodejs
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install -yq nodejs \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install MEAN.JS Prerequisites
RUN npm install --quiet -g gulp bower yo mocha karma-cli pm2 && npm cache clean

RUN mkdir -p /opt/mean.js/public/lib
WORKDIR /opt/mean.js

# Copies the local package.json file to the container
# and utilities docker container cache to not needing to rebuild
# and install node_modules/ everytime we build the docker, but only
# when the local package.json file changes.
# Install npm packages
COPY package.json /opt/mean.js/package.json
RUN npm install --quiet && npm cache clean

# Install bower packages
COPY bower.json /opt/mean.js/bower.json
COPY .bowerrc /opt/mean.js/.bowerrc
RUN bower install --quiet --allow-root --config.interactive=false

COPY . /opt/mean.js

# Run MEAN.JS server
CMD npm install && npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after much wrestling unsuccessfully trying to install docker on windows, I went back to the dockerfile to try and identify the core issue here. Fortunately I find a solution as follows..

NodeJS is attempting to install on Ubuntu.
In the dockerfile at the root of the app
Ubuntu version is configured as:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

simply change it to:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

I'm not sure if this is the best version to use for the build but it seems to be running successfully. Please feel free to amend/recommend an alternative solution. I'm new to Docker so pls be kind.